# Java-RS Return Array Not Object

Tags: java, restful-url

I am developing Java RESTfUl web services, I have a method return generic List in JSON format.
When MyList has two and more elements then it returns the array:

> [ {  name :"Murad" }, { name:"Ilkin" } ]

but when MyList has one element return an Object not an Array,

> {name :"Murad"}

I always want to return an Array not an Object

> [{name:"Murad"}]

Answer (score 0):

Trying like this code :

```
List<String> s=new ArrayList<String>();
s=result.getStrings();
return s;
```

it does not change anything.But this :

```
ArrayList<String> s=new ArrayList<String>();
s=result.getStrings();
return s;
```

can help you.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for reply I have Generics type example Employee Class its have more atribute,then can help me this code?

Comment: Yes,it must help you.